# Simple example needed for loading jsonp with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I apologize that this may be a duplicate issue on the forum but I am having terrible trouble understanding the process of loading in jsonp with jquery.

I simply would like to write a function that prints out the json data for the from the following url:

http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2012-02&lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592

a simple example function would be fantastic!

Thanks,

-- Dan

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: David, obviously I have looked through this but as I explained I'm still struggling with the basics. Therefore a simple example with my desired URL will help greatly towards me understanding how this works...

Comment: @user2263300: You can't load that JSON data with jQuery. It's not JSONP and your cross-origin request will get blocked by browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you can't do this. The API you mention serves JSON, not JSONP. There's no way you can somehow turn that into JSONP from the browser.

Because this is a cross-site request, you won't be able to read the JSON content from the browser.

There are only a couple of options:

1. On your own server (where your page is hosted), put up a proxy that loads their JSON and passes it through to your code. Make sure that this is OK with whatever terms of service the API has.
2. Get the policeapi2 people to either support JSONP requests themselves, or support CORS requests.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we load JSONP with jquery

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function (data) {
         $('body').text(data);
     }
 });
```

Remember, The url should serve a jsonp for this to work, The Url you provided do not return JSONP so you cant do that this way.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5P7C/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). This is an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2012-02&lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592',
    success: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
})
```